# Converting a 3x10 to 1x10 with QR dropouts (NOT Thru axle)

Tags: axle, quick-release

Wondering about the load and potential issues of converting a 3x10 to a 1x10.

Bike is aluminum with QR axles.

Should I worry about the rear axle twisting out of the dropouts on the higher gearing?

Dropouts are vertical.

Comment: 1x10 produces less tension on your chain and frame, unless the one chainring is smaller than smallest of the triple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have no issues from a frame stand point. Just make sure you keep a good chain line and you're good to go!

There are lots of 1x10 QR bikes out there. And with the popularity of the 1x10 these days your options will be abundant. Also you will want to look into Narrow/wide chainrings for the front if you haven't already. With a good one a chain guide is not necessary unless you're doing downhill stuff.

Comment: Yes for options! I've got the setup in my "shopping cart" ready to pull the trigger, when this small thought crossed my mind...

Comment: Pull it! As long as you have the right bottom bracket and all the components figured out you should be good to go!